# create an application in excel using python for a user without python

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am doing an application in Excel and I'd like to use python language. I've seen a pretty cool library called xlwings, but to run it a user need to have python installed.

Is there any possibility to prepare this kind of application that will be launch from a PC without Python?

Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: You seem to want to run a Python application on a machine without a Python installation.  Am I confused ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do it, but it seems to be imposible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small workaround could be to package your application with cx_freeze or pyinstaller. Then it can run on a machine without installing python. The downside is of course that the program tend to be a bit bulky in size.

Comment: Finally I've used cx_freeze. Thanks, that works perfectly but, as you said, it is a bit bulky in size.

Comment: If you are happy, so am I and if you feel for it please mark as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

no. you must need install a python and for interpreting the python function etc.

Comment: Ohh.. I don't like it. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: This *does* provide an answer to the question.  Perhaps it could be more clearly expressed but OP asks *Is there any possibility ... ?* and this states (correctly as far as I understand) *no*.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using xlloop. This is a customized client-server approach, where the client is an excel .xll which must be installed on client's machine. 
The server can be written in many languages, including python, and of course it must be launched on a server that has python installed. Currently the .xll is available only for 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for (i.e.- "without python"), but you could ship it as a virtualenv .zip folder with all the necessary packages and respective python installation included in the folder... and also include a run.command bash executable inside the folder that the user can click on to run your program. You'll have to tell the user (inside a README.txt or something) how to enable the executable... For a particular application mine looked like...

```
Please complete the following steps after installation of MyApplication.zip:  
Step 1: Move the MyApplication folder to your Desktop.  
Step 2: Open your Terminal in Go then Applications then Utilities.  
Step 3: In the Terminal, paste cd ~/Desktop/MyApplication  
then press Enter.  
Step 4: Then, paste chmod +x run.command  
then press Enter.  
From now on, clicking the “run” file in MyApplication will run the application.  
If clicking the “run” file still doesn’t work, then do…  
Click Ok on the popup then Open System Preferences then Security & Privacy 
then Click on Open Anyway button then Click Open button on the popup.  
NOTE: Please do not move or delete the MyApplication folder, or any of its files.
```

Then my run.command executable looked like the following:

`cd ~/Desktop/MyApplication
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/lib-old:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/Extras/lib/python:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/plat-mac:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python2.7:$HOME/Desktop/MyApplication/lib/python27.zip
source bin/activate
python main.py`

Three things are important here:
1) In run.command, I first change directory into the virtualenv I created for this project. I'm not trying to be dynamic here, since this is all just a quick hack of a solution, so as part of the README.txt, I simply tell the user to put the folder they downloaded onto their desktop. Otherwise, the cd command wouldn't work.
2) I set the client's PATH variable, separating entries with colons. You can see a list of the paths you'd need using a quick check on your computer...

    `import sys
    for path in sys.path:
        print path`

3) I then call source bin/activate to activate the virtualenv.
4) I then execute my main.py file, which is in the top level of my virtualenv, along with run.command.
5) I only wrote this bash file for Mac OS X, so I don't know how it would translate to windows PCs. I think the only thing that'd change is that the path literals would need to use backslashes instead of forward slashes, but again, I haven't done this for windows so I'm uncertain.

Read more about setting up a virtualenv here:  https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html
Finally, note that you will not be able to send your final, working .zip folder over most email services, since they tend to prevent people from sending executables back and forth, so you'll have to use a service like Dropbox or something to send it to people.